# Having trouble integrating Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, repository-pattern

This one is driving me mad. I've read the Ninject docs, I've read the docs for the Ninject MVC extension, I've lost count of how many related SO questions I've read, and I have no idea where the problem is with my code.

I'm building a webapp in ASP.NET MVC 4, and I'm using Ninject to bind repository interfaces. The docs say that if you add Ninject using NuGet (which I did), then it wires everything up for you so you don't need to have your application inherit from `NinjectHttpApplication` (so I haven't) and you just need to add your bindings in `NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices()`, (which I have). I have an `IRepository<T>`, and a `Repository<T>`. The user repository has a few extra methods for login and registration, so there's a separate `UserRepository` which implements `IRepository<User>`. My bindings therefore look like this:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(BaseRepository<>)).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<User>)).To(typeof(UserRepository)).InRequestScope();
```

The docs, and a couple of SO questions, also mention that if you added Ninject though NuGet (which I did) then it sorts out the controller factory for you and you don't need to implement your own Ninject-y controller factory (so I haven't). My controllers inherit from a `BaseController`, which has a constructor that accepts a set of `IRepository`-compatible repositories. Now, from what I've read, when I try to use a controller, Ninject should recognise the `IRepositoriy` parameters and provide them. It doesn't. Even if I put the `[Inject]` attribute on the constructor, it still gets ignored - the parameterless constructor gets called instead. If I remove the parameterless constructor, I get a compile error complaining that there isn't one.

What have I missed? How do I get Ninject to provide my repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird, I am unable to reproduce the problem you are describing.

Steps:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application using the Internet template
2. Install the `Ninject.MVC3` NuGet
3. Define some classes:

   ```
   public interface IRepository<T>
   {
   }

   public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
   {
   }

   public class User
   {
   }

   public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User>
   {
   }

   public abstract class BaseController<T>: Controller
   {
       protected BaseController(IRepository<T> repository)
       {
           this.Repository = repository;
       }

       protected IRepository<T> Repository { get; private set; }
   }

   public class HomeController : BaseController<User>
   {
       public HomeController(IRepository<User> repository): base(repository)
       {
       }

       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return Content(this.Repository.GetType().ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
4. And wire them up in `~/App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs`:

   ```
   private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
   {
       kernel
           .Bind(typeof(IRepository<User>))
           .To(typeof(UserRepository))
           .InRequestScope();
   }
   ```
5. Run the application and the proper instance of the repository gets injected into HomeContorller.

Comment: Huh. I only just started this project, so I'm starting to wonder if it would be less work to just start over...

Comment: Yeah, start over. It took me like less than a minute to mock that sample for you.

Comment: Well.. not sure if this counts as a "solution" considering the problem somehow doesn't exist, but it explains in a nice concise post the process I had to piece together from vague and/or oddly-written docs, so you get the accept :P